# inflate throwing OutOfResourcesException

Tags: android, listview, adapter, layout-inflater

I am trying to do a list with custom adapter, but in the part of code when I call inflate, I am getting `OutOfResourcesException`, I made several tests but I didn't discovered why

When the debug executes this line: `rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_chat, parent, false);`
then the the exception is called.

```
public class ListChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public class Contact {
        private String name;
        private String sentence;
        private Bitmap img;

        Contact(String name, String sentence, Bitmap bmp) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sentence = sentence;
            this.img = bmp;
        }

        void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        void setSentence(String sentence) {
            this.sentence = sentence;
        }

        void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) {
            this.img = bmp;
        }

        String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        String getSentence() {
            return this.sentence;
        }

        Bitmap getImg() {
            return this.img;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textSentence;
        ImageView img;
    }

    private static int count = 0;
    private static List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    private Context context;

    public ListChatAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void addItem(Contact contact) {
        contacts.add(contact);
        count++;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView==null){

            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            // Exception here
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_chat, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.textName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text_name);

            viewHolder.textSentence = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text_sentence);

            viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_chat);

            // store the holder with the view.
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) rowView.getTag();
        }

        // object item based on the position
        Contact objectItem = contacts.get(position);

        // assign values if the object is not null
        if(objectItem != null) {
            // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
            viewHolder.textName.setText(objectItem.getName());
            viewHolder.textSentence.setText(objectItem.getSentence());
            viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(objectItem.getImg());
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

And the layout call **list_chat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/vlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation = "vertical" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_chat"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_name"    
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_chat"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/img_chat"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_sentence"    
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_chat"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/img_chat"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_sentence" />

</RelativeLayout>
</Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of your incoming images. Even though your view is given small dimensions, the entire image is loaded by default then scaled. So if you are loading very large images, you can quickly exhaust the heap of the VM.

The other thing to look at is your use of `RelativeLayout` and the alignment of the child views.  The last `TextView`, id of `text_sentence` has `android:layout_below="@id/text_sentence"`, so it is telling the system to align it below itself.  I'll be that Eclipse or Android Studio (whichever you are using) is flagging this as a problem.  So what is happening on inflation is the layout is being inflated but `RelativeLayout` is recursively trying to measure and layout this child view and runs out of resources.  You most likely meant to set this alignment to be below `@id/text_name`.

Also, note that right now now the parent `LinearLayout` isn't doing anything for you, so it is extra overhead you can eliminate by removing it.  This won't make much of a difference for a list of 1, but as you start to get many items in your list this is going to have a negative performance impact.  Whenever you can you should eliminate unnecessary views from the view hierarchy of your layouts.

Comment: But this image I used for the test is the default icon from app,  and I used this image in other example without inflate and I didn't get problems.

Comment: What is the resolution of the image?

Comment: It would also be helpful to provide the logcat output w/stacktrace.  How many entries are in your list?

Comment: Even without the image I had problem on this same line, I have only one entry.

Comment: I think I see the issue.  Will update my answer above.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem I forgot to specify the layout_width and layout_height, and how you said Andrdoid had problems to measure the components.